Is the iPhone 16 2x zoom optical or digital?
The main camera on the iPhone 16 is advertised as "2x Telephoto" by Apple, and the tech specs describe it like this:

48MP Fusion: 26 mm, ƒ/1.6 aperture, sensor‑shift optical image stabilization, 100% Focus Pixels, support for super-high-resolution photos (24MP and 48MP)
Also enables 12MP 2x Telephoto: 52 mm, ƒ/1.6 aperture, sensor-shift optical image stabilization, 100% Focus Pixels

What does this actually mean? All the marketing implies it's optical zoom (including being listed in the compare page as "optical zoom levels"), however what I'm getting from the tech specs is that it's just cropping the 48MP photo down to 12MP, which would be digital zoom.
How does the 2x zoom on the iPhone 16 actually work?
